# How to utilize Android Picasso for loading images in non public-html place of the server?

Tags: php, android

In an Android application, for loading an image with Picasso, URL of the image is needed but I want to put the images in **non** public-html place of the server where there is no URL availability

How to utilize Android Picasso for loading images in non public-html place of the server?

code requested in comments:
The `Android` code for upload and communicate with `PHP` code of the server is as following:

```
public SendJSONToServer(Context context,String FileNewName,String url,String uri, SendJSONToServer.OnEventListener callback ) {
        this.url = url;
        this.uri = uri;
        this.FileNewName = FileNewName;
        mCallBack = callback;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (checkNetworkConnection() == false)
            return  null;
        try {

            JSONHttpHandler3 sh = new JSONHttpHandler3();
            String srv_RC ;
            srv_RC = sh.makeServiceCall3(FileNewName,url,uri);

            if (srv_RC.equals("Move To Server Failed"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if (srv_RC.equals("Move To Server successful"))
            {
                return "Move To Server successful";
            }
            else
            {
                return srv_RC;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            mException = e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (mCallBack != null) {
            if (mException == null) {

                if(result == null)
                {
                    mCallBack.onFailure(null);
                }
                else
                {
                   mCallBack.onSuccess(result);
                }
            } else {
                mCallBack.onFailure(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OnEventListener<T> {
        public void onSuccess(T object);
        public void onFailure(String f);
    }

    public boolean checkNetworkConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && (isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected())) {

        } 
        else {

        }
        return isConnected;
    }
```

and this too:

```
public String makeServiceCall3(String FileNewName,String FileDestination,String sourceFileUri) {

        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        String fileName = FileNewName;
        String upLoadServerUri = null;
        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = FileDestination;//"http://www.koalaapp.ir/DB/upload3.php";

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + sourceFileUri);
            return "0";
        }
        else {

            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                int length = fileInputStream.available();
                Log.e(TAG, "lllllllllllllllllll: "+length);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();


                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    total.append(line).append('\n');
                }


                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

                if (total.toString().contains("Move successful") == true )
                {
                    return "Move To Server successful";
                }
                else
                {

                    return "Move To Server Failed";
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
                return "Move To Server Failed";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "111Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return "Move To Server Failed";

            }
        }
    } // End else block
```

and for file access of PHP code, the following code is a sample to work with files (this is JSON sample but it could be image too):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("j000000033w.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide me with a help link or sample code ?